# flutter search from API Json

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to make a searchbar that fetch data from mysql , but i have a problem that when i call data fetch function it returns
Instance of '_Future<List>'
this is my code

```
Future<List<Students>> getStudents(String id) async {
  var url = 'http://localhost/getStudents.php';
  final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
    'id':id,
  });
  var res = jsonDecode(response.body)['fname'] as List;
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return res.map((std) => Students.fromJson(std)).toList();
  }else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load shows');
  }
}
```

my class :

```
class Students{
  final int id;
   final String fname;
   final String sname;
   final String tname;
  
const Students( {
  required this.id,
required this.sname,
 required this.tname, 
required this.fname,
});
   factory Students.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Students(
     id: json['Id'],
     sname: json['secname'],
     tname:json['thirdname'] ,
     fname: json['firstname'],
   );

}
```

Comment: I would say that this happens when you forget to add an await keyword when you called it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getStudents` is a future function and you need to `await` for it:

```
List<Students> result = await getStudents('');
```